# Debugging F# applications using Visual Studio

Tags: .net, visual-studio, debugging, f#

I need to use Visual Studio in order to debug an F# application. What do I need to do?

I know about the `EntryPoint` attribute but it is not simple to do that. First of all I build my application in Viual Studio, so I do not know how to tell him that a certain file must be the last in compilation order. Furthermore, even if I succeeded in compiling, how could I start Visual Studio debugger?

My main need is just using debug tools just like breakpoints and more in ordeer to follow what a certain function of mine works.

Thankyou

PS: VS2010 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you put the file containing the entry point at the bottom of the project explorer tree, it becomes the last in compilation order. You can use shortcut key Atl + Down/Up Arrow or simply drag and drop. Once it is done, set the breakpoints and you can start debugging.

Comment: I don't think drag-n-drop works for rearranging compilation order.

Comment: @Daniel Sorry I was wrong. It doesn't even allow to do drag and drop operations in the project explorer. The other way is editing the fsproj file manually.

Answer (score 3):

ALT+UP/DOWN (in Solution Explorer) rearranges file compilation order (this can also be done through the context menu). Debugging in F# works the same as in C#. Click in the margins (or F9) to set a breakpoint. F5 to run/debug.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I do not missunderstand your question.

You can change the compilation order of your files with ALT+up or ALT+down.
You do not need to place the EntryPoint attribute, when your files are in the right order.
Put the file to start with down at the bottom of the file list.

The debugger is started in the menu: Debug->Start Debugging (or F5 on my machine).

Breakpoints are in the same menu: Debug->...

Comment: But my one is a f# project... You're telling me that by defining an EntryPoint in a function it will go? but how can I deal with compilation order? Furthermore, where should I chane the order of my files for compilation? in the solution explorer window?

Comment: Yes, the comilation order is changed in the solution explorer. And the last file in your solution will be the entry point for your application. Btw, are you using Visual Studio 2010?

Comment: I never said something about defining a 'EntryPoint in a function'. Can you clarify please?

Comment: Yes it is 2010, sorry I should have mentioned it earlier... Without an entry point the debgger tells it does not have any executable to track...